FirebaseCommandException while running flutterfire configure
I am trying to configure the Firebase in my project. After installing the firebase-tools package using npm, I try to configure the Firebase project in my flutter project but i am getting the error all time like FirebaseCommandException:

An error occurred on the Firebase CLI when attempting to run a command.

I try to logout and login back again.Same issue.
I try to create a new project and tried configure but same issue. My node version is v20.17.0 and npm version is 10.8.2. I have tried using the latest version node package also but same result.
Krishnas-MacBook-Air:car_rent_app krishnaprasad$ dart pub global activate flutterfire_cli
Package flutterfire_cli is currently active at version 1.0.0.
Downloading packages... . 
The package flutterfire_cli is already activated at newest available version.
To recompile executables, first run `dart pub global deactivate flutterfire_cli`.
Installed executable flutterfire.
Warning: Pub installs executables into $HOME/.pub-cache/bin, which is not on your path.
You can fix that by adding this to your shell's config file (.zshrc, .bashrc, .bash_profile, etc.):

  export PATH="$PATH":"$HOME/.pub-cache/bin"

Activated flutterfire_cli 1.0.0.
Krishnas-MacBook-Air:car_rent_app krishnaprasad$ export PATH="$PATH":"$HOME/.pub-cache/bin"
Krishnas-MacBook-Air:car_rent_app krishnaprasad$ flutterfire configure --project=car-rental-app-5cb05
FirebaseCommandException: An error occured on the Firebase CLI when attempting to run a command.
COMMAND: firebase --version 
ERROR: The FlutterFire CLI currently requires the official Firebase CLI to also be installed, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#install_the_firebase_cli for how to install it.


can you post your error?

@gopelkujo I have added the CLI image.

Please post the code and error as text, not screenshot

@toyotaSupra Done

as stated in the error ERROR: The FlutterFire CLI currently requires the official Firebase CLI to also be installed, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#install_the_firebase_cli for how to install it did you already install the firebase cli?

Run: firebase logout
Then: firebase login

Tried not working.
